# Disable users from copying question's text even from dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, dom

We have got an online quiz web app, a decent prizes every day is given to the winners, and recently we noticed a significantly increased number of winners, we suspect there is an open cheating door, and accordingly, we have covered a lot of areas but our main concern right now is to remove the question text from the DOM because users might be able to copy the question's text and search for an answer.

`user-select` is set to `none`, but they might disable it from dev tools even though dev tools cannot be opened within the site, users might work around this by opening it before visiting the site.

We've tried rendering SVG contains paths of text, but it raised too many styles issues, some of them were impossible to handle (text direction, padding, new lines..etc)

I am looking for a solution to **disable** users from selecting the question's text even from dev tools.

Comment: If SVG didn't work for you, you may try canvas, though the former seems to me more suitable.

Comment: No matter what you do you will never be able to prevent a screenshot being passed to OCR program that reads the text

Comment: @charlietfl: I guess, for certain appliances (like online quiz with time limits), images may suit the purpose since OCR and googling in this case will take too long.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Does canvas supports RTL, new lines, changing font family to a specific font loaded via CSS?

Comment: @charlietfl Each question got limited time (10 sec), I don't think they would have enough time

Comment: There is no way to prevent people from reading the DOM. You can obfuscate it all you like but at the end of the day it's plaintext.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thanks for sharing. I just was playing around with it trying to do just like that, but do you think users might be able to access the stored question in any mean? reverse engineering or something. Since each question is stored in state and upon submitting it gets replaced by the new question. SVG was more appealing because it covers this hole; no plain text was stored, only unreadable paths.

Comment: Are you doing the svg rendering server side? As for using OCR if there is money involved some simple automation could probably have the text into a web search relatively quickly

Comment: @MAS : You may render your images/components server-side.

Comment: Even if you could prevent from copying you can't do anything if anyone works with 2 accounts first for looking and taking screenshots (on computer or by handy-camera), googling afterwards as long as he needs and then use the second account for answering it with this solution. To pretend for this you had to use a big pool of questions and display them random.

Comment: @Sascha Our pool consists of ~7k questions and increasing daily.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I am working on a proof of concept right now, key points are 1. using Canvas 2. prepare it on the server-side, please feel free to submit an answer and I will update with the end result.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes server-side. I agree with you, this would be our next concern, perhaps some mechanism to detect OCR scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to render it using images(generated on the server) instead. However users can still type it over manually. There is nothing to prevent that.

Comment: There is a limited time for each question got only 10 seconds, if users couldn't copy paste programmatically or enabling `user-select` and then searching, then I don't think they would have enough time to cheat. As stated in the question images make it very difficult to style the page

Comment: @MAS Oh I skipped over that part. So there is still no way however you can look into detecting if devtools is open. There is some tricks to do that: https://dev.to/composite/a-simple-way-to-detect-devtools-2ag0